# Unable to solve error In h2o happening in kaggle kernels

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, h2o, kaggle

I am trying to run algorithms in H2o as the dataset is quite large and its a regression problem

I am competing in a kernel only competition named **Mercari Price suggestion  challenge**  and thus it requires  to run and check the code only in Kaggle Kernels.

I am using R language with an 8 GB RAM

Initially  I  was   able to run glm model and save output csv 
with the following code

```
library(glm2)
glm.model2 <- h2o.glm( y = y.dep, x = x.indep, training_frame = train1.h2o, validation_frame = valid1.h2o
,family = "gaussian")
```

Glm runs quickly in 12 sec without producing error but as soon as I try to run

either gbm or  basic deep learning  model  it produces error

```
library(gbm)
h2o.gbm(y=y.dep, x=x.indep, training_frame = train1.h2o,validation_frame = valid1.h2o, ntrees = 2000, max_depth = 4, learn_rate = 0.01)

library(randomForest)
rforest.model <- h2o.randomForest(y=y.dep, x=x.indep, training_frame = train1.h2o,validation_frame = valid1.h2o, ntrees = 1000, mtries = 3, max_depth = 4, seed = 1122)


 dlearning.model <- h2o.deeplearning(y = y.dep,
                                      x = x.indep,
                                       training_frame = train1.h2o,
                                       validation_frame = valid1.h2o,
                                       epoch = 60,
                                       hidden = c(100,100),
                                       activation = "Rectifier",
                                       seed = 1122
  )
```

I get the following error time and again.
Please suggest what can be done to solve this problem as glm is running very fine but all other are not at all running

```
Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = urlSuffix, : Unexpected CURL error: Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused
Traceback:
```

It fails even after reaching  10 to 11 percent for both  models and I want to know is there any hack or any measure so I can at least run these algorithms so that I can submit my result. I am unable to do built an ensemble model because of all this.

Any measure that can be used as I have run them in kaggle kernel only

Comment: The tag "ML" concerns the programming language, not machine "learning".

Comment: I have used the tag "machine -learning" not "ML"

Comment: No you didn't. It looks like you did because I replaced it for you a couple of hours ago.

Comment: Thanks@molbdnilo. Appreciate it

Comment: I think that you don't need packages gbm, glm or randomFrorest if you use h2o.  Did you type something like `library(h2o);
localH2O = h2o.init(nthreads = -1) ;` ?

Comment: YEs i did that before but still the error is apparent and glm runs fine but gbm,random forest and deepleraning produce the same error.

Answer (score 0):

> `Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused`

This is an issue caused by how Kaggle is running H2O in their kernels (which are probably Docker images).  The H2O R client is not able to connect to the local H2O server running at localhost:54321.

Something you can try is to start the H2O cluster on a different port. So instead of running `h2o.init()` do something like `h2o.init(port=44444)`.  If they are allowing many people to start H2O clusters on the same machine/port, that may cause some issues.  If you are already connected to the H2O cluster in your session, then first run `h2o.shutdown(prompt = FALSE)` before re-starting H2O on a different port.

I also suggest that you contact a Kaggle admin to see if they can help debug the issue.  We've seen issues like this before with Kaggle kernels.

Answer (score 0):

You're not able to connect to the server because [kernels don't have an internet connection](https://www.kaggle.com/c/introducing-kaggle-scripts). :)

Update: I've done some more digging and internet access shouldn't be the issue here. I'll file a bug.